# Erro ao consultar informações SQLite para uma listview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Bom dia! Sou novo no stack overflow e estou aprendendo android com java. quando vou abrir a activty que tem a listview o aplicativo crasha e apresenta esse erro

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.av2, PID: 3951
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.av2/com.example.av2.ListActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: nome (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, nome FROM fornecedor
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: nome (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, nome FROM fornecedor
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1240)
    at com.example.av2.FornecedorDAO.carregaDados(FornecedorDAO.java:45)
    at com.example.av2.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:33)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Essa é a classe FornecedorDAO:

```
public class FornecedorDAO {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Conexao banco;

public FornecedorDAO(Context context) {
    banco = new Conexao(context);

}
public String inserir(String nome, String cidade, String estado){
    ContentValues valores;
    long resultado;

    db = banco.getWritableDatabase();
    valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put(banco.NOME, nome);
    valores.put(banco.CIDADE, cidade);
    valores.put(banco.ESTADO, estado);

    resultado = db.insert(banco.TABELA, null, valores);
    banco.close();

    if (resultado ==-1)
        return "Erro ao inserir registro";
    else
        return "Registro Inserido com sucesso";

}
public Cursor carregaDados(){
    Cursor cursor;
    String[] campos =  {banco.ID,banco.NOME};
    db = banco.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.query(banco.TABELA, campos, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();
    return cursor;
}
```

}

Essa a classe ListActivity:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView lista;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    FornecedorDAO db = new FornecedorDAO(getBaseContext());
    Cursor cursor = db.carregaDados();

    String[] nomeCampos = new String[] {Conexao.NOME, Conexao.ID};
    int[] idViews = new int[] {R.id.matriculaFor, R.id.nomeFor};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adaptador = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.layout_lista,cursor,nomeCampos,idViews, 0);
    lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaFornecedores);
    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
}

public void TelaCadastro(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CadastroActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Esse é a classe que cria o banco:

```
public class Conexao extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String BANCO = "banco.db";
public static final String TABELA = "fornecedor";
public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String NOME = "nome";
public static final String CIDADE = "cidade";
public static final String ESTADO = "estado";
public static final int version = 1;

public Conexao (Context context){
    super(context, BANCO, null ,version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE "  + TABELA +" (" + ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                                                NOME + "TEXT," +
                                                CIDADE + "TEXT," +
                                                ESTADO + "TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

O erro pode estar atrelado ao você estar criando a tabela, tenta adicionar um espaço depois do nome e do tipo, caso contrário você estará retornando NOMETEXT ao invés de "NOME TEXT".

```
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE "  + TABELA +" (" + ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                                            NOME + " TEXT," +
                                            CIDADE + " TEXT," +
                                            ESTADO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(sql);
```